# Implementing Lambda Calculus true and false in Haskell

Tags: haskell, lambda-calculus

Perhaps this is a trivial question and I'm just not thinking about it correctly. If so, my apologies.

I would like to implement the lambda calculus true and false functions in Haskell and then use those to implement if-then-else.  Here's what I did.

```
true :: t1 -> t2 -> t1
true x y =  x

false :: t1 -> t2 -> t2
false x y = y

-- ifThenElse :: (t2 -> t1 -> t) -> t2 -> t1 -> t
ifThenElse cond thenPart elsePart =  cond thenPart elsePart
```

The commented-out `ifThenElse` type is what GHC generates. My concern is that `t` in that type should be constrained to be either `t1` or `t2`. Can I write a type for `ifThenElse` that accomplishes this?

Comment: check [this](http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses#a-yes-no-typeclass) up

Comment: No, because Haskell does not know that `cond` should be either `true` or `false`. For Haskell `cond` is a generic function.

Comment: You could write `ifThenElse :: (t -> t -> t) -> t -> t -> t`.

Comment: I know that Haskell doesn't know that `cond` must be either `true` or `false`. I'm asking how to require that it be that..

Comment: Switch on `RankNTypes` and demand `ifThenElse` take a condition of type `forall t. t -> t -> t`.

Comment: Two things. (1) Can we do it without extra features? (2) More important, I would prefer to allow `t1` and `t2` to be different.

Comment: @RussAbbott, what will you do with the information that they can be different?  Say you have `let x = ifThenElse b 42 "Foobar"`, how do you plan to use `x`?

Comment: I think I confused the issue by how I asked the question. I was thinking that `cond` should return either the `true` function or the `false` function. That result would be applied to the `thenPart` and `elsePart` and pick one. I suppose that the way GHC defined the `cond` type, the selection is made without requiring an intermediate `true` or `false` result first. I wanted to require the intermediate result. If that's not required there is no need to define the `true` and `false` functions at all, at least for defining `ifThenElse`. Does that make any sense? That was my original thought.

Comment: In the last line of code, you are just saying that `ifThenElse = id`. On the other hand, the expression `cond thenPart elsePart` can't have different types depending on `cond`. So you either stick with `Either t1 t2` or you make `t1` and `t2` be the same type.

Answer (score 0):

You want these:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
-- These are the only two values of this type...
true  :: l -> r -> Either l r
false :: l -> r -> Either l r
true  l _ = Left  l
false _ r = Right r

-- ...and they are the only possible arguments here.
ifThenElse :: (forall l r. l -> r -> Either l r) -> l -> r -> Either l r
ifThenElse = id
```

There's no way around `Either` if you want differing left and right types.